# How should I cut a long, curvy cactus?

Tags: houseplants, cactus, cuttings

I have received a cactus that is a bit curvy. Here's some pictures to give you an idea:

[image]

[image]

It's doing well right now but I'm concerned that the curve will eventually break it. Is it possible to cut this into segments and pot them separately?

Comment: The poor thing is missing sunlight so much!

Comment: @J.Chomel: Yes, I imagine that's how it got the way it is. It's in a sunnier spot now, but that can't correct the previous bends and curves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very much so. I have done similar cuts many times on cacti and succulents. If you cleanly cut off the top 6 inches or so and pot it up it should root quite easily. And then remove all but the bottom 6 inches and leave it to regrow and you will have two lovely cacti!

Comment: Is it possible to cut it into multiple segments? I think I have enough material for 3 or 4, including the part that's currently rooted. Also, with a top that's cut, will it start new growths from the root/base, or will the cut top heal and grow? Should it be watered well when rooted or left dry for a bit? I don't have much experience with cacti.

Comment: You can make at least 3-4. How tall is it? If you want lots, you can cut 2 inch sections. They will form roots at the bottom and the top will heal over, but will not look as good as the original obviously! I would do a large one from the top as it will be the nicest one in the long run. Keep them moist, but not soggy, or the base will rot.

Comment: Ok, I'll go for a big segment from the top and also at the bottom, and smaller segments in between the top and bottom segments. Can they all be rooted together in a cluster in the same pot or do they need space?    ...I need to know how many pots to buy tonight. ;)

Comment: Sounds good. I root smaller shoots from various cacti I have, and I generally put them in the same pot, but not touching until they root and then transplant them.

Comment: So I ended up only cutting it so that there are three segments in total. They've been potted for about three weeks, hope they work out.

Comment: Awesome, I hope it goes well.

Comment: It worked. I now have one very tall, less wiggly cactus, and two with stumpy tops that have 3 smaller cacti sprouting out of them, each. Should I just let these two keep growing with their 3 arms, or separate them and pot them on their own?