# Is this cactus unhealthy, especially at the bottom?

Tags: diagnosis, containers, transplanting, cactus

Our cactus is about 4 or 5 inches tall.  I think it's looking unhealthy in the lower half.  I also think it must receive a larger container.  Recommendations?   Thanks!

[image: Upright image]

Comment: repotting definitely not required for a while.  usual issues are too much water, not enough light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like root rot to me. How much do you water it and when?

In terms of saving it, you may be able to take cuttings from them as advised in this [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/25024/1929)

If you do, be careful not to over water it, especially whilst it is rooting as the new roots are very susceptible to rot. Water a small amount and then leave it until the soil is completely dry.

Use a free draining soil mixed with plenty of grit and of course a pot that drains easily.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Oops, it's been watered by different family members and together, watered too often!  It's in the brightest window sill in the house.